# cant push with git to live following tutorial

Tags: git, error-handling, ssh, zend-framework2, push

I followed this tutorial

http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment

I did everything, followed it to the tea.

I am on my local machine, I have made a change to one file, and do

```
git commit -a -m "test"
```

then:

```
git push
```

it then ask for my server password
so i input and i get this error:

```
stdin: is not a tty
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 504 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: **** Pulling changes into live
remote: 
remote: From /var/git/agriTech
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote: error: Your local changes to 'module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
remote: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
remote: Updating 5a53563..7236cb6
To root@217.199.160.153:/var/git/agriTech.git
   5b4fafd..7236cb6  master -> master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read quickly the tutorial.

On the server, you have local modifications in the repository `/var/www/myproject` (named from the tutorial conventions).
**This repository should never be updated directly** , otherwise it could contain unversioned modifications, which is not what you want.

**Error cause :** when you do a `git push`, `/var/git/myproject.git` tries to update `/var/www/myproject`, but since it has local modifications, update fails.

**Solution :**

- Go into `/var/www/myproject` on the server and run `git reset --hard HEAD`. This will remove all local modifications.
- Now you can retry a `git push` from your local machine, everything should be fine.

To avoid the problem in the future, you can add `git reset --hard HEAD` after the `unset GIT_DIR` line in the `/var/git/myproject.git/hooks/post-update` file.